# How to check my statement but like individually if it is coded as one

Tags: php, html, if-statement

This is a function i am currently using for registering of user account in php.

```
function checkpost($input, $mandatory, $pattern) {

    $inputvalue=$_POST[$input];

    if (empty($inputvalue)) {
        printmessage("$input field is empty");
        if ($mandatory) return false;
        else printmessage("but $input is not mandatory");
    }
    if (strlen($pattern) > 0) { //Checks for Input Validation
        $ismatch=preg_match($pattern,$inputvalue);
        if (!$ismatch || $ismatch==0) { // If is not match or is match = 0 
            printmessage("$input field wrong format <br>");
            if ($mandatory) return false;
            // header("location: registerform.php");
        }
    }
    return true;
}


$checkall=true;
    $checkall=$checkall && checkpost("name",true,""); //Mandatory
    $checkall=$checkall && checkpost("email",true,"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i");
    $checkall=$checkall && checkpost("password",true,"/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/");
    $checkall=$checkall && checkpost("nric",true,""); //Mandatory
    $checkall=$checkall && checkpost("mobile",true,"");
    $checkall=$checkall && checkpost("address",true,"");
```

I tried doing this way of method to check for the statement I have about but I am unsure how can i check like individually like email, password,nric. Is there something wrong with my ifelse cause when I do

```
// if (!$checkall) { The default error
    //  printmessage("Error checking inputs<br>Please return to the registration form");
    //  die();
    // }
```

This will work but I want to check each individual field and print it out. Please help me I'm struggling right now

This is the one I tried but the regex statement suddenly does not work and it will print out the wrong echo statement even if the email format is correct. Seeking help please help me thank you in advance

```
if (!$checkall=$checkall && checkpost("email",true,"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i")) {
        echo "Invalid email";
        die();
    }

    elseif (!$checkall && checkpost("password",true,"")) {
        echo "Invalid password";
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reorder your code for some prettier logic by wrapping the validation into a try/catch block. This will validate each entry, but throw an exception on the first error. When one happens the helper variable `$hasErrors` is set to true. So you know after validation if any one failed or not.

```
$hasErrors = false;
try {
    if (!checkpost("name", true, "")) throw new Exception("Name is missing");
    if (!checkpost("email", true, "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i")) throw new Exception("Wrong email format");
    if (!checkpost("password", true, "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/")) throw new Exception("Password insecure");
    if (!checkpost("nric", true, "")) throw new Exception("Nric?");;
    if (!checkpost("mobile", true, "")) throw new Exception("Mobile missing");
    if (!checkpost("address", true, "")) throw new Exception("Address missing");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $hasErrors = true;
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if (!$hasErrors) {
    echo "Success";
}
```

**Note:** You don't need the message for exception at all or print it! I've added it for demonstration purpose.